# Is it possible for two independent processes to share a memory mapping of a file?

Tags: ipc, shared-memory, mmap

I have two processes, p1 and p2, which need to read various parts of a large file - the same file - using `mmap()`. Read, but not write. The processes are started independently of each other - neither is a descendant of the other.

Now, obviously I can just have them both map the same file, and I assume the kernel might have some kind of optimization, e.g. not keep two copies of the same pages. But - can I do better than that by, say, mmapping into shared memory, or sharing an mmaped area?

Notes:

- The kernel is GNU/Linux 4.x
- The machine is x86_64

Comment: But if the two processes are reading different parts of the file, then there is nothing to share.

Comment: "can I do better than that by, say, mmapping into shared memory, or sharing an mmaped area" How is this different from sharing the same physical pages? Linux does that.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I misspoke; I meant different as in "various".

Comment: @HadiBrais: I was thinking of the overhead of setting up the mapping of a large file, which I would like to save.

Comment: You only have to map the parts of the file that you need to access. The rest of the file will not be mapped or loaded to physical memory. So the overhead is already minimal.

Comment: @HadiBrais: But I don't know in advance what I'll need to access; plus, combined, it's likely that most of the file will be accessed by one of the processes.

Comment: Why does that matter? Whenever process accesses any part of the file for the first time, that part will be loaded into physical memory. Any other processes that attempt to access a part that already been loaded will just soft-page-fault to the same physical pages. What is the overhead that you're trying to minimize or avoid? It seems to me that it's already minimal.